# Como dividir un array en dos?

Tags: javascript, array

Como dividir este array en dos arrays independientes de la longitud que sea. Entre los dos arrays deben contener a todos los alumnos, sin que ninguno se repita.
Gracias

```
var alumnos =["Carlos","Clara","Cristina","Fernando","Ivan","Lara","Mercedes","Rafael","Roberto","Sandra","Tania","Raulito","Milagros"];
```

Comment: Añade información extra, puedes hacer clic [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/125589/edit) para editar tu pregunta.

Comment: Pues ya lo cambie pero vamos que solo hay que dividir un array en dos, soy nuevo en esto, use concat para unirlo ahora como con splice? No caigo ahora mismo. Graciuas rene

Comment: @fran En este caso el método que sería de utilidad sería splice() para remover elementos del array. Debes tomar en cuenta que una parte tendrá más elementos en este caso ya que el total es un numero impar.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes dos opciones, dependiendo de si quieres mantener el array original intacto o no:

El método [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice) no modifica el array original, creando copias de una parte de éste:

```js
let alumnos =["Carlos","Clara","Cristina","Fernando","Ivan","Lara","Mercedes","Rafael","Roberto","Sandra","Tania","Raulito","Milagros"];

let mitad = Math.floor(alumnos.length / 2);

let inicio = alumnos.slice(0, mitad);
let final = alumnos.slice(mitad); // si no se indica el índice final, se usa la longitud del array como referencia

console.log('Primera parte:', inicio.toString())
console.log('Segunda parte', final.toString())
console.log('Array original', alumnos.toString());
```

El método [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice) modifica el array original, extrayendo una parte del mismo:

```js
let alumnos =["Carlos","Clara","Cristina","Fernando","Ivan","Lara","Mercedes","Rafael","Roberto","Sandra","Tania","Raulito","Milagros"];

let mitad = Math.floor(alumnos.length / 2);

console.log('Redondeamos hacia abajo, la mitad está en la posición', mitad);

let inicio = alumnos.splice(0, mitad);

console.log(inicio.toString()); //primera parte, extraída
console.log(alumnos.toString()); //array original, modificado, sólo tiene la parte final
```

Comment: Hola, me podrías ayudar dividiéndolo en 3 partes

Answer (score 1):

```
 let alumnos = ['Carlos','Clara','Cristina','Fernando','Ivan','Lara','Mercedes',
               'Rafael','Roberto','Sandra','Tania','Raulito','Milagros']
 let m1 = alumnos.splice(0,(alumnos.length/2));
 console.log("Mitad 1 --> ",m1);
 let m2 = alumnos.splice(0,alumnos.length);
 console.log("Mitad 2 -->",m2);
```

Espero esto te sirva, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta:

```
var alumnos = [1,2,3,4]
var index = alumnos.length;
var primeraParte = alumnos.slice(0, index/2);
var segundaParte = alumnos.slice(index/2,index);
console.log(primeraParte);
console.log(segundaParte);
```

Answer (score 1):

El total de tu array es impar y deseas dividirlo en dos, por lo tanto una mitad tendrá más elementos, puedes usar el método `splice()` para remover elementos de una array. Por cierto asegura de declarar correctamente el array, en este caso un array de cadenas:

```js
var alumnos =['Carlos','Clara','Cristina','Fernando','Ivan','Lara','Mercedes','Rafael','Roberto','Sandra','Tania','Raulito','Milagros'];


document.writeln("Total de elementos en array: " + alumnos.length + "<br>");
var mitad1 = alumnos.splice(0,alumnos.length/2);
document.writeln("Primera mitad: " + mitad1 + "<br>");

var mitad2 = alumnos.splice(0,alumnos.length);
document.writeln("Segunda mitad: " + mitad2 + "<br>");
```

Comment: El segundo splice es innecesario, a menos que quieras vaciar el array original.